# 10 digit phone number validation

Tags: validation

I'm using cform to capture internet leads on my website. I need a code so that people have to provide full 10 digit phone number or else it wont let them submit the request. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Answer (score 0):

Just get the length of what the user provides. check if they are all numbers, and if they are, assume that it is a number.